# Around a characterization for even perfect numbers, similar than Euclides-Euler theorem, in terms of totatives

Tags: nt.number-theory, factorization, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

In this post we denote the sum of divisors function as $$\sigma(n)=\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}d,$$ then an even perfect number is a positive integer $n\equiv 0\text{ mod }2$ for which $\sigma(n)=2n.$ As reference it's know for instance the Wikipedia *Perfect number*. In particular it is known the theorems due to Euclides and Euler.

The Euler's totient $\varphi(x)$ function is also a multiplicative function. Using the characterization for even perfect numbers due to Euler and Euclides

$$n=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$$
where $2^p-1$ is its associated Mersenne prime
one has the folowing claim.

**Claim.** *Let* $\lambda\geq 1$ *and* $\mu\geq 1$ *be fixed integers. Define, being* $2^{p}-1$ *a Mersenne prime, the relationship* $$m+1:=2^{p-1}.$$ 
*Then the identity*
$$\varphi((m+1)^\lambda(2m+1)^\mu)=m(m+1)^\lambda (2m+1)^{\mu-1}$$
*holds.*

I would like to know if it is possible to prove the following conjecture (I've tested it for some segments of integers, and I tried to get the proof for a case).

> **Question.** Prove or refute the following conjecture:
>
> *For any choice of* $\lambda\geq 1$ *and* $\mu\geq 1$ *integers, it holds that if an integer* $m\geq 1$ *satisfies* 
>   $$\varphi((m+1)^\lambda(2m+1)^\mu)=m(m+1)^\lambda (2m+1)^{\mu-1}$$
>   *then* $$(m+1)(2m+1)$$
>   *is an even perfect number.*
>
> **Many thanks.**

Thus in my view it should be a similar theorem/characterization for even perfect numbers by using the Euler's totient function instead of the sum of divisors function.

I hope that my question has a good mathematical content and that there aren't mistakes. Feel free to ask about the check that I did using a Pari/GP program, or criticize if this version of Euclides-Euler theorem is potentitally interesting.

Comment: All, the comparison with the characterization for even perfect numbers due to Euclides and Euler comes from the case $\lambda=\mu=1$, and from the fact that as a consequence of Euclides-Euler theorem for even perfect numbers $n=2^{p-1}\cdot(2^p-1)$ is a triangular number $n=\frac{M+1}{2}\cdot M$ where $M=2^p-1$ is its associated Mersenne prime. That's $$\sigma\left(\frac{M(M+1)}{2}\right)=M(M+1)$$ since $M$ is perfect. As it was said feel free to provide me the opinion if my **Claim** and related conjecture are potentially interesting. I am waiting for your feedback, many thanks.

Comment: Thus if you can to prove the conjecture in my **Question**, then (in particular)  the following characterization for even perfect numbers will be feasible: *An integer* $m\geq 1$ *satisfies the identity* 

$$\varphi((m+1)(2m+1))=m(m+1)$$
*if and only if* $(m+1)(2m+1)$ *is an even perfect number (being* $2m+1=2^p-1$ *its associated Mersenne prime).*

Comment: As aside comment I think that a similar claim and conjecture (a third and last characterization similar than Euclides-Euler theorem) are feasible in terms of the Dedekind psi function $\psi(n)$, in particular the conjecture: *An integer* $r\geq 1$ *satisfies* $$\psi\left(\frac{(3r-1)(3r-2)}{2}\right)=\frac{3}{4}(3r-1)^2$$
*if and only if* $\frac{3r-1}{2}(3r-2)$ *is an even perfect number greater than* $6$ *(being* $3r-2=2^p-1$ *its associated Mersenne prime).* As reference the Wikipedia *Perfect number* that refers the relationship between even perfect numbers and centered nonagonal numbers.

Comment: In my first comment was added that *..since* $M$ *is perfect...*, instead of the right claim *..since* $\frac{M+1}{2} M$ *is perfect...*

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, by far. Just some observations, and solutions to some cases for $m$.

Using the identity $\phi(n^m)=n^{m-1}\phi(n)$ and the fact that $(m+1,2m+1)=1$, we can say

$$\phi((m+1)^\lambda (2m+1)^\mu) = (m+1)^{\lambda-1} (2m+1)^{\mu-1} \phi(m+1) \phi(2m+1).$$

This should then equal $m(m+1)^\lambda (2m+1)^{\mu-1}$. After division, we are left with

$$\phi(m+1)\phi(2m+1) = m(m+1).$$

In particular, this identity is equivalent to the one in your question.

Let us make the substitution $s = m + 1$. Then $\phi(s)\phi(2s-1) = s(s-1)$

Suppose that $s=p^\alpha$. Then $(p-1) \phi(2p^{\alpha}-1) = p (p^\alpha - 1)$.

If $p=2$, this says that $\phi(2^{\alpha+1} - 1) = (2^{\alpha+1} - 1) - 1$. Because the only numbers for which $\phi(x)=x-1$ are primes, $2^{\alpha+1}-1$ is a prime and $s(2s-1)$ is indeed an even perfect number.

Otherwise, let us denote $2p^\alpha - 1$ as $x$. Thus, $\phi(x)=\frac p {2(p-1)} (x-1)$. Suppose $x=q^\beta r$, so that it is not squarefree ($\beta > 1$). This says that $2(p-1)q^{\beta-1}(q-1)\phi(r) = p(q^\beta r - 1)$. Taking this modulo $q$, we get a contradiction. Thus, $x$ is squarefree.

We can also see that $x$ cannot be a prime. If $x$ were a prime, we would get $\phi(x) = x-1 = \frac p {2(p-1)} (x-1)$, or that $p=2$.

However, I don't see how to proceed if $s$ is not a prime power, or if $2s-1$ is a squarefree composite number.

Comment: Many thanks  for your answer. I'm going to study it! I think that your simplifications are elegant and will be useful.